# A question which is surely a duplicate but got answered by High rep users as well

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I just discovered this today.

There was a question : [How to get the device Model Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38157217/how-to-get-the-device-model-name)

Any good user of SO can say that this is a duplicate at a glace. Though **people are going on answering the question and up-voting that question as well**.

Is there any action take by SO to the people who **encourage new users to ask duplicate question again and again by giving answer** to them for just gaining reputation??

> There should be some policy that if a 2k+ rep user answer a surely dupe
>   some action would be taken. We can mark the answer with some flag. The action need to be decided by SO i am
>   just **pointing out the crack in the wall**.

How could it be considered? I want to know it from the readers of my question ??

Please i haven't found any satisfactory comment or answer yet..!!

**EDIT :**

One more case same as the above one : [android update textview for every 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38199036/android-update-textview-for-every-30-seconds)

> Same case but a 5k+ rep user is answering the question the reputation
>   got some increment..!!

Comment: downvote those answers and add a comment explaining this.

Comment: @Shubhank:  That's not constructive.  Unless there's actually a duplicate that is being actively referenced, you're just punishing them based on a supposition.

Comment: i have done the same but i am talking in general thing. Is it +15 matters everyvery. Some have up-voted the question as well see there are two upvotes..!! Is it fare enough ??

Comment: @Makoto if the question is simply a duplicate as such shown in the source question - it is recommended to downvote. I won't suggest that generally for every possible duplicate.

Comment: @jankigadhiya poor question and answers are part of SO moderation problem. you just need to stick to solving the mess by giving close vote/flagging as duplicate. With more rep - you get better tools to counter these.

Comment: I approve with @jankigadhiya becuase when we flag to close the question as Duplicate and Moderator can close it before the question has Answer and it accept as well..

Comment: please take a look to my edit @Makoto

Comment: I mean @gnat found this duplicate, but I feel like it's appropriate.  You're looking for some kind of retribution, but there's no official process.  Your best best is to boost that feature request.

Comment: Hmya, calling these people 'high rep users' is just a small part of the SO deflation problem.  SO users want a forum, not a Q+A site, resistance is futile.

Comment: agree @HansPassant..!!